# Finding a function with some requirements

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

> Find a function $H$ such that $H(H(x)) = H(x)$ for all numbers $x$, and such that $H(1)=36$, $H(2)=\pi/3$, $H(13)=47$, $H(36)=36$, $H(\pi/3)=\pi/3$, $H(47)=47$.

Any hints would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you don't even require continuity, here's the minimal example:
$$
H(x) = 
\begin{cases}
36, &x=1 \text{ or } 36 ,\\
\pi/3 , &x= 2 \text{ or } \pi/3, \\
47 , &x=13 \text{ or } 47 \\
0 &\text{else.}
\end{cases}
$$
You can easily check that $H(H(x)) = H(x)$ for any $x$ and it satisfies the other conditions trivially.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I want the function to be defined using only one expression. (not a piecewise function)